# FreePlane node details extraction and casting

Tags: java, groovy, casting, mindmapping

this is a FreePlane Groovy code.
The task is to extract the node details and cast it to integer, or leave it equal to 1 if details are null (empty) or non-numeric. Initially, node details contain only "4" in plain text layout.

Here is my code:

```
def getRepetitions(node)
{
    if (node.details!=null){
        node['node.details']=node.details
        node['node.details.size()']=node.details.size()
        node['getPlain()']=node.details.getPlain()
        node['getPlain().size()']=node.details.getPlain().size()
        node['node.details.status']='not null'
     getRepetitions=(double)(node.details.getPlain())-48
    }else{
        node['node.details.status']='null'
        getRepetitions=1
    }
}
```

Here is a problem, as code doesn't convert text "4" to 4, but rather to 52 (which is incidentally ASCII code of "4"). And worse, when I substract 48, so that the difference is equal to number itself, it doesn't pay attention.

I wouldn't be posting this, if such functions as toNumber(...) or .to.num0 would work, but when trying to implement this I see

---

"message: No signature of method: org.freeplane.plugin.script.proxy.Proxy$NodeRO.toNumber() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [4]Line number: -1Result:No signature of method: org.freeplane.plugin.script.proxy.Proxy$NodeRO.toNumber() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [4] at line -1"

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get the number like this: `node.details.num`

The proxy mentioned in your error is [this](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/freeplane/plugin/script/proxy/Proxy.NodeRO.html) interface. That will tell you which methods are available for your nodes.

What is the deal with `getRepetitions=x`? That looks like VB code. The Groovy equivalent the `return` statement (or an expression).

Comment: I've already solved that problem: I had to use node.details.getPlain() method to get the text, and then use .toInteger() method to get a number.
Thanks anyway.